# Merge two sorted linklist recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I cant find anything wrong with the code but when i submit it two of the testcases giving runtime error . Please help me to figure out that error. I have checked it for atleast 30 custom testcases but it gives right output for all of them.

`Code`

```
public static Node mergeTwoList(Node head1, Node head2) {
    Node c = null;        
    if (head1 == null) {
        return head2;
    } else if (head2 == null) {
        return head1;
    }

    if (head1.data < head2.data) {
        c = head1;
        c.next = mergeTwoList(head1.next, head2);
    } else {
        c = head2;
        c.next = mergeTwoList(head1, head2.next); 
    }
    return c;
}
```

If somebody figure out anything please do tell me.

Comment: What 's the error?

Comment: Online tool did not give specific detail. It just displayed runtime error

Comment: @KillerDeath might be stack overflow due to recursion.Do u find anything?

Comment: Your implementation is not tail-recursive. What is the runtime error you are seeing?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga not any specific detail about runtime error.

Comment: Does your specification allow you to mutate the two lists? Or does it require you to produce a third list?

Comment: @Prince solution looks good and should produce expected output.
But first read about online environment time and memory constrains. It may be because of  stack overflow because input given is too long in those 2 test cases. 
So I suggest us use iterative solution rather than recursive one to get those tests passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is stackoverflow, because you use recursion, and recursion will produce stack, and if the linklist is long, it may cause stackoverflow.

There is a similar question on leecode, and I solve it with iterative,
I paste the solution in my blog, although the explanation is in Madarin, the code can still be your reference. The link is provided below:
http://codecrazer.blogspot.tw/2017/07/leetcode-21-merge-two-sorted-lists.html